# Erro no Gradle - Startup failed

Tags: android, gradle

> O que há de errado com o meu Gradle?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.thiago.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {support:design
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

 dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile('com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'
}
```

Erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu que te pergunto! O que tem de errado no seu Gradle? Se está aparecendo algum erro, você tem que colocar na sua pergunta, senão fica difícil encontrar uma resposta.

Comment: Desculpe,declarei o erro ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo porque não existe a propriedade `support` no Gradle, como consta na linha `buildTypes {support:design`, bem como na própria mensagem de erro salienta:

> In case you tried to configure a property named 'support', replace ':'
>   with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.

Remova o `support:design` do seu `buildTypes`. Veja abaixo como deve ficar:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta !